# UnsatisfiedDependencyException, BeanCreationException, and IllegalArgumentException errors

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, h2

I am creating a project that functions like an ecommerce website, but I keep getting the errors mentioned in the title. I tried looking on other threads, and they talked about adding different annotations to the classes. For example, I added the @EntityScan and @ComponentScan annotations to my main class, but I am still getting the same errors. Here are the exact error messages, and below that is my code:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'categoryService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'categoryRepository': Error creating bean with name 'categoryRepository' defined in com.ecommerce.website.repository.CategoryRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on EcommerceWebsiteApplication: Not a managed type: class com.ecommerce.website.model.Category
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:712) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:692) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:127) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:481) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1397) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at com.ecommerce.website.EcommerceWebsiteApplication.main(EcommerceWebsiteApplication.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'categoryRepository' defined in com.ecommerce.website.repository.CategoryRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on EcommerceWebsiteApplication: Not a managed type: class com.ecommerce.website.model.Category
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1751) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:709) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.ecommerce.website.model.Category
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.JpaMetamodelImpl.managedType(JpaMetamodelImpl.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:496) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:77) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:69) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:246) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:211) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:194) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:229) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:113) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1797) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1747) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
```

Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.ecommerce.website.repository")
@ComponentScan("com.ecommerce.website.service")
@EntityScan("com.ecommerce.website.model")
public class EcommerceWebsiteApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EcommerceWebsiteApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Controller class

```
package com.ecommerce.website.controller;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

import com.ecommerce.website.model.Category;
import com.ecommerce.website.service.CategoryService;

//Category ID still having issues
//Need to add methods for Category delete and update methods 
@Controller
public class AdminController {
    
    //Injecting dependency
    @Autowired
    CategoryService categoryService;
    
    //This method maps for /admin endpoint. It shows the adminHome.html page. The method is @GetMapping because you are getting information 
    //@return the adminHome page
    @GetMapping("/admin")
    public String adminHome() {
        
        //Display html page
        return "adminHome";
    }
    
    //This method maps for /admin/categories endpoint. It shows the categories.html page. The method is @GetMapping because you are getting information
    //@return the categories page 
    @GetMapping("/admin/categories")
    public String getCat(Model model) {
        
        model.addAttribute("categories", categoryService.getAllCategories());
        
        //Display html page
        return "categories";
    }
    
    //This method maps for /admin/categories endpoint. It shows the categoriesAdd.html page, but before that, it creates
    //a model that is sent to the html file via Thymeleaf. The categoriesAdd.html page is a form for adding a category
    //The method is @GetMapping because you are getting information
    //@param model will hold the category object so that the form can add information to it 
    //@return the categoriesAdd page 
    @GetMapping("/admin/categories/add")
    public String getCatAdd(Model model) {
        
        //Adding the model name "category", and creating a new Category object and putting it in the model
        model.addAttribute("category", new Category());
        
        //Display html page
        return "categoriesAdd";
    }
    
    //This method maps for /admin/categories endpoint. It allows the user to add a category to the list of categories
    //The method is @PostMapping because you are sending information
    //@param category gets its value from the ModelAttribute, which gets its value from the form
    //@return the categories page 
    @PostMapping("/admin/categories/add")
    public String postCatAdd(@ModelAttribute("category") Category category) {
        
        //Calling categoryService to add the category
        categoryService.addCategory(category);
        
        //Redirecting to page that shows all categories 
        return "redirect:/admin/categories";
    }
```

Service

```
package com.ecommerce.website.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.ecommerce.website.model.Category;
import com.ecommerce.website.repository.CategoryRepository;

@Service
public class CategoryService {

    //Injecting dependency 
    @Autowired
    CategoryRepository categoryRepository;
    
    //This method calls categoryRepository to add a category to the database  
    //@param category is the category that is being added 
    public void addCategory(Category category) {
        
        //Saving the category to the database 
        categoryRepository.save(category);
    }
    
    //This method calls categoryRepository to retrieve a list of categories 
    //@return the list of categories  
    public List<Category> getAllCategories() {
        return categoryRepository.findAll();
    }
    

    
//  public Optional<Category> findCategoryById(String id) {
//      
//      Optional<Category> category = categoryRepository.findById(id);
//      
//      return category;
//      
//  }
}
```

Repository

```
package com.ecommerce.website.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.ecommerce.website.model.Category;

@Repository
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, String> {

    

}
```

POJO

```
package com.ecommerce.website.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

@Entity
@Table
public class Category {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "category_id")
    private int id;
    
    private String name;
    
    
    public Category() {
        
    }
    
    public Category(int id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    } 
    
    
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./db
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

server.port=8080
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ecommerce</groupId>
    <artifactId>ecommerce-website</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ecommerce-website</name>
    <description>Ecommerce website using Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security -->
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>-->
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Front end

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css"
          integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" >
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img th:src="@{/images/logo.png}"  src="../static/images/logo.png" width="auto" height="40" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt=""/>
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto"></ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/admin}" href="#">admin-home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/logout}" href="#">logout</a>
                </li>

            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome back, Admin</h1>
    <p>Easily manage your data from this admin <mark>CMS</mark></p>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 pt-3" >
            <div class="card" style="background-color:white;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Categories</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">Manage the categories section here.</p>
                    <a href="#" th:href="@{/admin/categories}" class="card-link btn btn-primary">Manage</a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 pt-3" >
            <div class="card" style="background-color:white;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Products</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">Manage all the products here.</p>
                    <a href="#" th:href="@{/admin/products}" class="card-link btn btn-primary">Manage</a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `@EntityScan("com.ecommerce.website.model.*")`

Comment: @tgdavies Thank you for your response! If I try using what you said, I still get the same errors.

Comment: Hi, please disregard my last message. What you said helped me out, but I had to add the ".*" to my other annotations in the main class. Now, my http://localhost:8080 URL works, but if I add /admin, I get a 404 error. Do you know why that is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove this dependency from `pom.xml` and try again.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! The issue is that if I do what you said, then I am not able to use "import javax.persistence.Entity;" and "import javax.persistence.Entity;" in my POJO.

Comment: Hi, I solved this issue. I had to add the ".*" to my other annotations in the main class. Now, my http://localhost:8080 URL works, but if I add /admin, I get a 404 error. Do you know why that is?

Comment: Can i know the reason why you want to use javax.persistence.* classes? Spring boot 3 upgraded javax.persistence.* to jakarta.*

Comment: The tutorial I am following uses javax.persistence. If I change to jakarta, do you think the issues may be resolved?

Comment: Yes it will be resolved

Comment: @Sohaib - any update on this? Did you tried?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. Your solution helped me out, so thank you for that! Also, it turns out, I was missing some dependencies that were mentioned in the tutorial I am following. I also made ComponentScan have 0 arguments. These things solved my issue.

Comment: Glad to know that your issue resolved , if my solution helped request you to please accept the answer so that it help others as well.

Comment: Sure! I did that.

Answer (score 0):

keep only this annotation

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class EcommerceWebsiteApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(EcommerceWebsiteApplication.class, args);
}
 @Autowired
 private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

}
```

you nedd to add an interface like this

```
public interface CategoryService2 {
public void addCategory(Category category);
public List<Category> getAllCategories();
}
```

and modify the classe like this:

```
@Service
public class CategoryService implements CategoryService2{

private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

public CategoryService(categoryRepository){
super();
this.categoryRepository = categoryRepository;
}
@Override
public void addCategory(Category category) {
    
    categoryRepository.save(category);
}
@Override  
public List<Category> getAllCategories() {
    return categoryRepository.findAll();
}
```

and remove the annotation @Repository from CategoryRepository and try to modify String in Long

```
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, Long> {

 }
```

Modify the class Category like this.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Ecommerce")
public class Category {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "category_id")
private Long id;
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;


public Category() {
    
}

public Category(int id, String name) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
} 
    
}
```

and try with and without this dependecy:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

modify the controllore like this:

```
@Controller
public class AdminController {
private CategoryService2 categoryService2;
public AdminController(CategoryService2 categoryService){
super();
this.categoryService2 = categoryService2;
}

//This method maps for /admin endpoint. It shows the adminHome.html page. The method is @GetMapping because you are getting information 
//@return the adminHome page
@GetMapping("/admin")
public String adminHome() {
    
    //Display html page
    return "adminHome";
}

//This method maps for /admin/categories endpoint. It shows the categories.html page. The method is @GetMapping because you are getting information
//@return the categories page 
@GetMapping("/admin/categories")
public String getCat(Model model) {
    
    model.addAttribute("categories", categoryService2.getAllCategories());
    
    //Display html page
    return "categories";
}

//This method maps for /admin/categories endpoint. It shows the categoriesAdd.html page, but before that, it creates
//a model that is sent to the html file via Thymeleaf. The categoriesAdd.html page is a form for adding a category
//The method is @GetMapping because you are getting information
//@param model will hold the category object so that the form can add information to it 
//@return the categoriesAdd page 
@GetMapping("/admin/categories/add")
public String getCatAdd(Model model) {
    
    //Adding the model name "category", and creating a new Category object and putting it in the model
    model.addAttribute("category", new Category());
    
    //Display html page
    return "categoriesAdd";
}

//This method maps for /admin/categories endpoint. It allows the user to add a category to the list of categories
//The method is @PostMapping because you are sending information
//@param category gets its value from the ModelAttribute, which gets its value from the form
//@return the categories page 
@PostMapping("/admin/categories/add")
public String postCatAdd(@ModelAttribute("category") Category category) {
    
    //Calling categoryService to add the category
    categoryService2.addCategory(category);
    
    //Redirecting to page that shows all categories 
    return "redirect:/admin/categories";
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried what you said, but I still get the following errors: UnsatisfiedDependencyException, BeanCreationException, and IllegalArgumentException

Comment: Hi, I solved this issue. I had to add the ".*" to my other annotations in the main class. Now, my http://localhost:8080 URL works, but if I add /admin, I get a 404 error. Do you know why that is?

Comment: post your front end code

Comment: Sure! I added that to the bottom